# Yarn issues with html-webpack-plugin and @cypress/webpack-dev-server

Tags: vuejs3, cypress, html-webpack-plugin

I am having issues with `vue-cli-service build` not being able to find `html-webpack-plugin`. This is already defined in `devDependencies` on `package.json`:

[package.json](https://pastebin.com/q5kSVVjz)

with the following log excerpt

["yarn build" log](https://pastebin.com/0ALsJ32t)

I note that during `yarn install`, I see the following warnings:

["yarn install" log](https://pastebin.com/EgtTL0Uk)

My theory is a yarn cache issue and conflicting cache stores.

If I remove `html-webpack-plugin` from devDependencies and leave everything to yarn, it complains about missing `html-webpack-plugin`. Clearing all of my local yarn cache and reinstalling - same issue. Deleting the existing `yarn.lock` and rerunning install, same. issue.

If I manually run `yarn install && yarn add -D html-webpack-plugin`, I get the same warnings, but `yarn build` works. I have a temporary workaround in yarns scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "install:dev": "yarn && yarn add -D html-webpack-plugin"
}
```

yarn does not give a dependency

```
 % yarn why html-webpack-plugin
yarn why v1.22.19
[1/4]   Why do we have the module "html-webpack-plugin"...?
[2/4]   Initialising dependency graph...
[3/4]   Finding dependency...
error We couldn't find a match!
✨  Done in 0.24s.
```

But we have dependencies on `html-webpack-plugin-4` & `html-webpack-plugin-5`

```
% yarn why html-webpack-plugin-4
yarn why v1.22.19
...
info Reasons this module exists
   - "@cypress#webpack-dev-server" depends on it
   - Hoisted from "@cypress#webpack-dev-server#html-webpack-plugin-4"
...

% yarn why html-webpack-plugin-5
yarn why v1.22.19
...
=> Found "html-webpack-plugin-5@5.5.3"
info Has been hoisted to "html-webpack-plugin-5"
info Reasons this module exists
   - Specified in "devDependencies"
   - Hoisted from "@cypress#webpack-dev-server#html-webpack-plugin-5"
   - Hoisted from "@vue#cli-service#html-webpack-plugin-5"
...
```

But this is not really how yarn is supposed to work... Does anyone have a better solution, or perhaps there's something wrong in my initial project setup?

Comment: Please edit your op with the output of `yarn why html-webpack-plugin`

Comment: It doesn't give me a dependency:

 % yarn why html-webpack-plugin
yarn why v1.22.19
[1/4]   Why do we have the module "html-webpack-plugin"...?
[2/4]   Initialising dependency graph...
[3/4]   Finding dependency...
error We couldn't find a match!
✨  Done in 0.24s.

Comment: question updated with results...

Comment: Thats intresting...try now `yarn why html-webpack-plugin-4` as well as `yarn why html-webpack-plugin-5`. Btw, your version of yarn is very old. The first thing I'd do is make sure you update to the latest (https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install)

Comment: Updated the OP with more why... So you can see why i suspect yarn cache is a problem with @cypress and @vue#cli-service

Comment: Honestly this looks like a yarn 1 resolution bug. Its getting confused because `@cypress/webpack-dev-server` is using `npm:` aliases on this package, and `@vue/cli-service`  does not. It is aliasing `html-webpack-plugin` to `html-webpack-plugin-5` for the vue package also, when it should not. Your version of yarn is very old. I'd suggest upgrading and seeing if that works before banging your head on it any further. This kind of thing was quite common on yarn 1 in my experience. Failing that, we can try some `resolutions` hacks.

Comment: (I also wouldn't rule out just using pnpm...its linking logic is so much better)

Comment: That was the solution. Many thanks @adsy - the problem was the yarn version. A quick search and following https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/migration fixed the problem.

Kudos to you!

Comment: @adsy, if you put your last comment in an answer (rather than comment), I'll mark it as the solution, and you'll get credit for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments this looks like a Yarn 1.x resolution bug. `@cypress/webpack-dev-server`'s `package.json` uses `npm:` alises to map `html-webpack-plugin-5` to v5 of `html-webpack-plugin`.

That's all well and good but `@vue/cli-service` depends on `html-webpack-plugin` also, and does not want it aliased. Yarn 1, seemingly due to a bug, also aliases it for that dependency too, so it can't find it where it expects it.

Yarn 1 is old and upgrading it to the latest fixes the issue.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments above, this was the problem, and it's been marked as the solution... many thanks @adsy, nice sleuthing.

The solution was simple: A quick search and following https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/migration fixed the problem.